# is there any need to index b again as it is already a under primary

Tags: mysql, index

Is there any need to index b again as it is already a  under primary-
if **primary(a,b)**  and in query we have `where b=' ';`

Is there any need to **index(b)** again individually because while indexing it will take left column first then thinks of the next.

Thanks in advance!, and please help me out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have index on (a,b) and a query with b = ? then that query can't make efficient use of that index. There are DBMS that can make use of the index in a decent way, but mysql is not one of those.

Comment: I have one more question. if primary(a) and columns are (a,b,c,d,e) with index b and index d, then column a will support as matrix form for query where a=' ' and b=' ' or need to index(a,b) again

Comment: You won't need the index (a, b) if index (a) is unique (primary) for a query with where a=? and b=?